# Node-red Azure Cloud table storage CSV file

Tags: node.js, csv, azure, azure-table-storage, node-red

I'm trying to read a CSV file and send over the data line by line to Azure Table Storage. I've made the data unique using the time stamp adding a variable per message. However if I send two lines of data in two messages. Only the second message comes across and the first one throws an error:

This is message one:

```
{
  "tableName":"name",
  "action":"I",
  "partitionKey":"part2",
  "rowKey":"1476649418331",
  "data":{"Column1":"Row1C1","Column2":"Row1C2","Column3":"Row1C3"}
}
```

Returning:

```
16-10-2016 22:23:39Azure Table Storage
msg : string [163]
Error while trying to save data:StorageError: The specified entity already exists. RequestId:cedf2110-0002-007f-4eeb-275e5e000000 Time:2016-10-16T20:23:40.3597774Z
```

This is message two:

```
{
  "tableName":"name",
  "action":"I",
  "partitionKey":"part2",
  "rowKey":"1476649418332",
  "data":{"Column1":"Row2C1","Column2":"Row2C2","Column3":"Row2C3"}
}
```

Returning:

```
16-10-2016 22:23:39Log
msg : string [11]
data saved.
```

This is my node-red flow:

```
[
{"id":"9a96640e.8ac6a8","type":"tab","label":"Flow 1"},
{"id":"79f08138.3591e","type":"debug","z":"9a96640e.8ac6a8","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"payload","x":724.5,"y":119,"wires":[]},
{"id":"6ba900e3.b8c68","type":"function","z":"9a96640e.8ac6a8","name":"dynamic","func":"msg.topic = msg.payload; \nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":163.5,"y":192,"wires":[["e9ba66a6.2609f8"]]},
{"id":"881bed10.69e5","type":"function","z":"9a96640e.8ac6a8","name":"merge","func":"if (!context.value) {\n context.value = 0;\n}\ncontext.value +=1;\n\n\n\nvar RowKey = String(msg.topic + context.value);\nvar Data = msg.payload;\n\nmsg.payload = {\"tableName\": \"name\", \"action\": \"I\", \"partitionKey\": \"part2\", \"rowKey\": RowKey, \"data\": Data};\n/*msg.payload = {\"tableName\": \"name\", \"action\": \"I\", \"partitionKey\": \"part2\", \"rowKey\": \"row13\", \"data\": {\"Column\": \"Value13\"}};*/\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":404,"y":166,"wires":[["180d09fa.2000c6"]]},
{"id":"180d09fa.2000c6","type":"json","z":"9a96640e.8ac6a8","name":"","x":543,"y":210,"wires":[["79f08138.3591e","8b1be5eb.5dcbc8"]]},
{"id":"8b1be5eb.5dcbc8","type":"Table Storage","z":"9a96640e.8ac6a8","name":"Azure Table Storage","x":766.5,"y":209,"wires":[["fe41d516.3e8208"]]},
{"id":"fe41d516.3e8208","type":"debug","z":"9a96640e.8ac6a8","name":"Log","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"true","x":794.5,"y":403,"wires":[]},
{"id":"7deb1c15.482474","type":"inject","z":"9a96640e.8ac6a8","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":true,"x":76,"y":306,"wires":[["6ba900e3.b8c68"]]},
{"id":"17a020b6.e0f95f","type":"csv","z":"9a96640e.8ac6a8","name":"CSV parser","sep":"\\t","hdrin":true,"hdrout":true,"multi":"one","ret":"\\n","temp":"A,B,C,D","x":464,"y":305,"wires":[["1dc33972.1e6177","881bed10.69e5"]]},
{"id":"e9ba66a6.2609f8","type":"file in","z":"9a96640e.8ac6a8","name":"File Reader","filename":"D:\\TESTCSV.txt","format":"utf8","x":264,"y":305,"wires":[["17a020b6.e0f95f"]]},
{"id":"1dc33972.1e6177","type":"debug","z":"9a96640e.8ac6a8","name":"","active":false,"console":"false","complete":"false","x":443,"y":405,"wires":[]}
]
```

Does someone have an idea were this error comes from?

Comment: In the mean time I found out that the problem can be avoided if I use a delay node with action: Limit rate to.. This limits the rate of which messages are send to the Azure node. The only downside is that it's drastically reduces the performance since the max amount message that can be send across is 1 second. So any other ideas are more then welcome.

Comment: Have you reviewed guidance samples in GitHub? E.g. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-table-node-getting-started samples

Comment: How you implement the functionality? could you provide some key code snippet for add entities to Azure Table Storage? Have you used batch?

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. However, are you ware I'm using node-red?